# Proving a set of two vectors cannot span a 3-dimensional space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to prove that a set of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot be a spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Intuitively , it makes a lot of sense, however I need to prove it for my homework assignment. This is for a proof-based linear algebra class.

Edit:

Apologies,
This far I have tried to prove that in general we cannot find a set of constants that satisfies the spanning definition.

Essentially taking 2 vectors $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and saying for these vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\exists \alpha_1, \alpha_2$ such that $\alpha_1\cdot v_1 + \alpha_2\cdot v_2=x$ where x is any arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I then took the components of the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ and set them equal to the components of the arbitrary vector $x$. That will yield a system of equations. However I’m stuck and cannot figure out if this is even the right approach.

I don’t think it is enough for me to simply say "since the vector space has 3 dimensions we need at least 3 vectors with three components to span it" without proof.

Hope that’s better.

Comment: Perhaps consider dimension?

Comment: You need to find a nonzero vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^3$ that isn't a linear combination of two given vectors $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^3$. A promising candidate is the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) $c = a \times b$.

Comment: "*I then took the components of the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ and set them equal to the components of the arbitrary vector $x$. That will yield a system of equations.*" This is a good start. Have you tried to find a relation between $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ and $[x,y,z]^T$? Notice if $v_1,v_2$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$, the relation must exist; otherwise, they are not spanning vectors for this space.

Comment: Abstract duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853818

Comment: Are you allowed to use the rank-nullity theorem? If so, a linear combination of two three dimensional vectors corresponds to a $3\times 2$ matrix times a $2\times 1$ vector which, since the two vectors span $\mathbb R^3$, would mean that a matrix with two columns has rank $3$. If you are not allowed to use the rank-nullity theorem then that argument might be considered circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try Contradiction.

When we can span $R^3$ with 2 vectors from $R^3$ , we must atleast get $V_1=(1,0,0),V_2=(0,1,0),V_3=(0,0,1)$ which can then easily generate all other vectors.
Hence we have to show that we can not get $V_1,V_2,V_3$ through Contradiction.

Assume we can get those 3 vectors using 2 vectors $U_1=(u_{11},u_{12},u_{13}),U_2=(u_{21},u_{22},u_{23})$.

$r_{11}U_1+r_{12}U_2=V1 \tag{1}$
$r_{21}U_1+r_{22}U_2=V2 \tag{2}$
$r_{31}U_1+r_{32}U_2=V3 \tag{3}$

With (1) , where the last component is $0$ , we get :  $r_{11}u_{13}+r_{12}u_{23}=0 \tag{4}$
With (2) , where the last component is still $0$ , we get :
$r_{21}u_{13}+r_{22}u_{23}=0 \tag{5}$

Subtracting the two , after cross multiplying , we can eliminate $u_{13}$ to get $r_{12}r_{21}u_{23}-r_{11}r_{22}u_{23}=0$ & we can eliminate $u_{23}$ to get $r_{11}r_{22}u_{13}-r_{12}r_{21}u_{13}=0$

This indicates that either (A) $u_{13}=u_{23}=0$ or (B) $r_{12}r_{21}-r_{11}r_{22}=0$
We see that Case (A) indicates that third component can never go Non-Zero to generate $V_3$ , hence Contradiction.
We can then check that Case (B) indicates that $V_2$ is always a multiple of $V_1$ , hence Contradiction.

[[
this answer seems too long , though the core idea is very simple
somebody else might give shorter arguments using some theorems
]]

Answer (score 1):

What even does it mean "vector space has three dimensions"? Depending on your course it may be a shorthand for "this space has three independent vectors spanning the space", "vectors in the space are isomorphic to triplets of real numbers" or something else entirely. In the second case, notice that a triplet of ($\left(\begin{matrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)$, $\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)$, $\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right)$) is independent and spans the whole set of triplets, so I'll be working with the first definition.

Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be those vectors. If our vectors $v_1, v_2$ were able to span the whole space, they would be able to produce those vectors as their linear combinations as well:
$$\begin{cases}e_1 = c_{11}v_1 + c_{12}v_2 \\
e_2 = c_{21}v_1 + c_{22}v_2 \\
e_3 = c_{31}v_1 + c_{32}v_2 \end{cases}$$
Let $c_{11} \neq 0$ (we can do that since at least one of the coefficients in each row is non-zero). Then multiplying by $k = \frac{1}{c_{11}}$ and after some manipulations:
$$\begin{cases}ke_1 = v_1 + kc_{12}v_2 \\
e_2 - kc_{21}e_1 = (c_{22}-kc_{12}c_{21})v_2 = \alpha v_2 \\
e_3 - kc_{31}e_1 = (c_{32}-kc_{12}c_{31})v_2 = \beta v_2 \end{cases}$$
Recall that a set of vectors is called *linearly independent* if any nontrivial (= "with at least one non-zero coefficient") linear combination of those vectors isn't zero. Left sides of the first two rows satisfy that and thus $\alpha \neq 0, \beta \neq 0$ and we can write:
$$\beta (e_2 - kc_{21}e_1) - \alpha (e_3 - kc_{31}e_1) = 0$$
Which produces a nontrivial zero linear combination of $e_1, e_2$ and $e_3$. Since we arrived to a contradiction, our initial assumption must have been false.

This argument generalizes to any number of dimensions: if $n$ independent vectors can be spanned by $n-1$ then we can express all $n$ vectors, subtract the first row and have $n-1$ independent vectors spanned by $n-2$, then repeat. In other words, there can be no more than one *finite* $n$ such that $n$ independent vectors span the whole space. When that is the case, we call that space $n$-dimensional.

Comment: I am not sure whether you saw my earlier answer , I just wanted to let you know that I made the same argument there , no worries though !!

Comment: @Prem I did see but I believe it was important to point out that a) there's a difference between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a three-dimensional space and b) this proof is the very foundation of a concept of an "$n$-dimensional space" as opposed to specific linear spaces. So, I tried to put a bit more emphasis on generalization.

Comment: I agree that these are valid Points [ +1 from me ] where we could check that $C^n$ has Dimension $2n$ to highlight the important nuances !